# A question containing many sub-questions

Tags: discussion

A question on representation theory has recently been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150577/quick-questions-about-representation-theory) and it contains many sub-questions. The question at the moment has one close vote and from the comments, a lot of the sub-questions in there are allegedly covered in textbooks. Personally I am keen for the question to be closed because it is difficult to answer the question in its current format (The current 1 close vote is not from me).

However that being said I think if the *individual* sub-questions were to be posted there could be some interesting input from some of the users of this site. How do we deal with such a situation? Obviously one way would be for the OP to delete his question and then ask the individual sub-questions as questions by themselves. Otherwise, do the moderators have powers to "break up" a post like that into individual posts?

Comment: Another way would be for you (and others) to vote to close the question, and then to post the pieces individually.

Comment: For the record: the question is now deleted.